# Create DIGITAL hash of string. Java

Tags: java, hash

I receive a flow of objects from web-service. The limitation from a client is that these objects should not be saved in database - so in this case I have to create my own ID of each object for future identification purpose.

One of the way is to use SHA256 algorithm to create a hash based on concatenation of object's attributes. 
So a hash might be like this:

> 07993ae34bf09e0afdfac7dd728b326095dcf4f68fa1d09e2e8cfb57f214bc5d

However, I work with external client system that **accepts only digital ID**s (type of Long).

Is there any way/algorithm to create digital hash from string?

P.S. Addtition. What I need at final is to receive ID of type Long for objects. However without saving them into database and thus basing only on concatanation of their attributes. I would think about creating hash consists only from digits and that would be applied to Long type. However, if there are some cleaver ways I would appreciate them.

Comment: I'm not sure what "digital hash" means.  However, if you simply mean "a hash that fits into a long", then you might consider just truncating e.g. the SHA256 result to 64-bit (i.e. 16 hex digits).

Comment: @Kirill If I am not mistaken you are going to get id (type long) back from the hash, right?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for your comment. Do I understand right that a hash from SHA256 might be somehow converted into Long type? If so I would appreciate that you describe this in the answer.

Comment: A simple approach is `new BigInteger("07993...bc5d", 16).longValue()`, which leaves you with a `long` containing the least significant 64 bits of the digest value.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive Long number from hash here is the following function:

```
private Long createId(String name) throws Exception {
    Long id = new BigInteger(getHash(name), 16).longValue();

    return id;
}
```

Just to show how hash is created:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

private String getHash(String s) throws Exception {

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec("Password".getBytes("UTF-8"), ""));

    byte[] ret = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    return Hex.encodeHexString(ret);
}
```